# Changing sconce from flourescent to halogen

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting

The new sconce has two black wires and  ground. Can it be used in existing location which has one black and one white wire?

Comment: Yes. One of the black wires would go to the white. Not sure what this has to do with the kind of bulb you are using, though.

Comment: Because of your assistance, I was able to change the sconce myself. Thanks so much!

Comment: glad it worked!